# Regarding proving a set theoritic argument which is to be used in proving equivalence of Dynkin system

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am proving equivalence of two forms of Dynkin system and some relations related to algebra and $ \sigma $ algebra properties. 
Here I am thinking of using argument that - Given two arbitrary non empty sets whose intersection is non empty, we can always break or form 3 sets from those two sets such that those 3 sets are pair wise disjoint. 
It seems fine by venn diagrams but could someone tell me how to prove it rigorously if it is always true?

Comment: It depends exactly what you mean. Certainly whenever $A,B$ are sets, their union $A\cup B$ is the disjoint union of $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus A$, and $A\cap B$. However, these sets don't all need to be nonempty (even if $A\not=B$): consider e.g. $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @Noah Schweber Thank you